# How do I skip text from a specific tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanna extract text from div by specific class. In this div I have text and extra span tag with specific class, which I don't want. So, how get text from div and ignore text from span?

A tree looks like:

```
<div class="desc"><h3 class="text-15 margin-bottom-10">Some desc:</h3>Some 
title <br/>
- text <br/>
- text<br/>
<br/>
text <br/>
<br/>
<br/>
text <br/>
@ <br/>
<br/>
text <span class="some_class">TEXT WHICH I DONT WANT</span> <br/>
<br/>
text <br/>
text <br/>
text </div>
```

So now I get have:

```
desc = source.find('div', class_="desc").text
```

and get full text with span. I try use decompose(), text=True, recursive=False but doesn't work. Anyone have idea how solve it?

Comment: What output do you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the span tag and decompose.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<div class="desc"><h3 class="text-15 margin-bottom-10">Some desc:</h3>Some 
title <br/>
- text <br/>
- text<br/>
<br/>
text <br/>
<br/>
<br/>
text <br/>
@ <br/>
<br/>
text <span class="some_class">TEXT WHICH I DONT WANT</span> <br/>
<br/>
text <br/>
text <br/>
text </div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
item=soup.find('div', class_='desc').find('span')
item.decompose()
newitem=soup.find('div', class_='desc')
print(newitem.text)
```

Output:

```
Some desc:Some 
title 
- text 
- text

text 


text 
@ 

text  

text 
text 
text
```

Comment: Yeah, works! I tried do this in this way before, but without good result.. I wondering how BS know that I 'decompose' tag from soup variable...

Answer (score 0):

`.extract()` should do the trick:

```
html = '''<div class="desc"><h3 class="text-15 margin-bottom-10">Some desc:</h3>Some 
title <br/>
- text <br/>
- text<br/>
<br/>
text <br/>
<br/>
<br/>
text <br/>
@ <br/>
<br/>
text <span class="some_class">TEXT WHICH I DONT WANT</span> <br/>
<br/>
text <br/>
text <br/>
text </div>'''

import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.find('span').extract()
desc = soup.find('div', class_="desc").text
```

**Output:**

```
print (desc)
Some desc:Some 
title 
- text 
- text

text 


text 
@ 

text  

text 
text 
text
```